# Make the submenu to be in the center according to its parent menu and width according to its content

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with `ul` and `li`. And some of the menu has sub menu inside another `ul` and `li`. Now all the submenu are aligned out of order. I need to make the sub menu to be perfectly centered according to their parent li. How can I achieve it?

Demo [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/xwOZRa)

```
<ul id="lorem-ipsum-main">
    <li id="btn-header-wrapper" class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-T">T</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T1">T1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T2">T2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T3">T3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T4">T4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-E"><b>E</b></a>
    </li>
    <li id="btn-justify-wrapper" class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-gender">Gender</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-M">M</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-F">F</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-other">other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-btn" id="btn-list-wrapper">
      <a href="#" id="btn-list">List</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-1list">List 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-2list">List 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>
</ul>
```

Comment: Both answers are great. Now it depends on you which one you like the most for you design to be in.

Answer (score 2):

How about this we make the child ul `width:100%` while making the parent `li {position:relative}` this allows us to change the `top` and `left` value of the child ul so the end result looks like **[this](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/JYKGrw?editors=110)**

Code:

```
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px lightgray;
  top:100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: Its great. But suppose, if the width of the content inside sub menu is more than the parent li menu, it just cross the width. Could you help me with making the width of the ul (sub menu) according to its conent and the not the parent menu?

Comment: In that case making sub menu's width fixed something like `80px` would work but the sub menu's would now overlap because we have a fixed width header. We can make the sub menu's `hidden` by default and have them appear when we hover over the parent `li` which is what most sites use these days, for that you have alot of tutorials on how it works.

Comment: Yes, eventually that's what I am going to do using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the submenus to be as wide as they need to be ***and*** centered on their parent `li` then you can use this:

```
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; /* positioning content */
}

#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space:nowrap; /* menu as wide as it needs to be */
  left: 50%; /* align halfway over */
  transform:translateX(-50%); /* pull back half own width */
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px lightgray;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MaeKVQ)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear_both {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper {
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  width: 190px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 18px;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main > li:first-child {
  color: green;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main > .main-btn:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn:hover {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px lightgray;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul li {
  padding: 4px;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul li:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="lorem-ipsum-wrapper">
  <ul id="lorem-ipsum-main">
    <li id="btn-header-wrapper" class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-T">T</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T1">T1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T2">T2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T3">T3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-T4">T4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-E"><b>E</b></a>
    </li>
    <li id="btn-justify-wrapper" class="main-btn">
      <a href="#" id="btn-gender">Gender</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-M">M</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-F">F</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-other">other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-btn" id="btn-list-wrapper">
      <a href="#" id="btn-list">List</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-1list">List 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" id="btn-2list">List 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <span class="clear_both"></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how I want. But, I also need it to be able to use in mobile browser (say opera mini). And I don't think it support transform. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Nope, you'd have to use separate styles for Opera Mini...every other mobile browser supports it. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Ok, I will have to check with my boss.

Answer (score 0):

You use jquery I see, so I tried to solve your problem with some jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lorem-ipsum-main > li").each(function() {
      var li_el = $(this); 
      ul_el = li_el.find("ul");
      ul_el.css("left",""+((li_el.innerWidth()-ul_el.outerWidth())/2)+"px");
    });
});
```

and updated this in your css:

```
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 18px;
  position: relative;
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul li {
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvBBpZ

Answer (score -2):

**New idea:**

(now the main menu gets the width of the submenu)

```
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 18px;
  height: 17px; /*Max-height of the Top-Main-Btn*/
}
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px lightgray;
  width: 100%; /*the sub UL has 100% width of it's parent */
}
```

Here is the edited CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avZdVR

**Old idea:**

I would do it in that way, change these two:

```
#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; /*you need to be able to place the sub ULs*/
}

#lorem-ipsum-wrapper #lorem-ipsum-main .main-btn ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px lightgray;
  width: 90%; /*the sub UL has 90% width of it's parent */
  left: 5%; /*the space on the left and right side is 5% */
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdMVeX

Comment: I'd be great if you provided another fiddle as the user did, so that he can easily run it and check for the result, instead of having to copy-paste your code into his document.

Comment: suppose, if the width of the content inside sub menu is more than the parent li menu, it just cross the width. Could you help me with making the width of the ul (sub menu) according to its conent and the not the parent menu?

Comment: I don't want the main menu to get the width of the submenu. Could you please help me that.

Comment: No I don't want the menu to get the width of submenu. I just need the submenu to match the width of its content.